# Extending Element in MooTools gives error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of null"

Tags: javascript, mootools, extend

I have this very simple MooTools script:

```
var MyElement = new Class({
    Extends: Element
});
```

which gives the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of null**

I'm using MooTools 1.4.5, full without compatability.

If I change the class it extends to any other class, it works fine.

What's going on here? Is this a bug?

EDIT:

Same thing happens with Implements: Element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out [on this page](https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/195-class-element-can-t-be-extended):

> element is not extendable as its not a real class.

This is because it is mostly an interface wrapper ('proxy') around your browser's native internal classes wrapping 'real' elements. There is a 'workaround' for this though with the `toElement` function. If you implement it on an object or class, passing the class to the $ function will automatically invoke it, as such making your class behave completely like an Element, and allowing you to use aggregation instead of (faulty!) inheritance to wrap browser elements.

[Example of toElement](http://www.clientcide.com/best-practices/5-advanced-techniques-for-mootools-development/).